# IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY in Linux to get the Device Controller Transfer Length

Tags: linux, driver, storage, device

I have been using IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY through the STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR in Windows to get the storage device controller maximum transfer length which will be use as my buffer allocation size for raw read or write access to the storage device.

I need information if Linux has similar approach to determine the maximum transfer length of a device controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already figure it out where I could get the information after long search on the net.

Comment: I already figure it out where I could get the information after long search on the net.  <br/> You just need to browse the Linux folder /sys/block/sdX/queue with which it contains SysFs used by the Kernel.  <br/> The file 'max_segment_size' corresponds to the maximum segment size of the device. Although you can use 'max_hw_sectors_kb' which corresponds to the maximum number of kilobytes supported in a single data transfer.